# Multiple regression - singularity issues

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, singular-matrix

I am trying to fit multivariate regression models to my data; however, I get singularity warnings. Please find a part of my data below:

```
Cat_1 <- c("LP", "LP", "LP", "LP", "GR", "GR", "GR", "LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "NI", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "CA", "CA", "JO", "CA", "CA", "TI", "PR", "TI", "TI", "AQ", "TI", "AQ", "TI", "KI", "AT", "AT", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", NA, NA, NA, "TS", "TS", "GE", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR")

Cat_2 <- c("CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CR", "CY", "CY", "CY", "CY", "CY", "EG", "GR", "GR", "GR", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "GR", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP")

Cat_3 <- c("EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "PE", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "PE", "EX", "EX", "EX", NA, NA, NA, "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "DR", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX", "EX")

Cont_1 <- c(0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 22.00, 22.00, 22.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00,  0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 55.00, 55.00, 55.00, 55.00, 55.00, 55.00, 55.00, 55.00, 33.78, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 20.00, 20.00, 48.00, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78, 33.78)

Response <- c(0.3474338, 0.3459840, 0.3459840, 0.3516871, 0.4205923, 0.4055125, 0.4175813, 0.6818209, 0.6857756, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5174143, 0.3546506, 0.5418190, 0.6052847, 0.5385959, 0.3295108, 0.5209747, 0.5199027, 0.5209747, 0.4618320, 0.6849975, 0.4132942, 0.3019946, 0.3281736, NA, NA, NA, 0.3865485, 0.4562354, 0.4198557, 0.3209418, 0.2956085, 0.3920888, NA, NA, 0.4949614, 0.4949614, 0.4949614, 0.5185092, 0.5185092, 0.5185092, 0.5185092, 0.5185092, NA, 0.7081736, 0.7081736, 0.7081736, 0.7174453, 0.7174453, 0.7174453, 0.6790109, 0.6790109, 0.6790109, 0.7050356, 0.7050356, 0.7050356, 0.6922349, 0.6922349, 0.6922349, 0.6922349, 0.6922349, 0.6922349, NA, NA, NA, 0.6265795, 0.6265795, 0.4186085, 0.6110061, 0.6288103, 0.5619780, 0.5793262, 0.6648705, 0.4948839, 0.5891485, 0.5565717, 0.5347567)

myData <- data.frame(Cat_1, Cat_2, Cat_3, Cont_1, Response)
```

When I try to fit:

```
lm(Response ~ Cat_1 + Cat_2, data = myData)
```

or

```
lm(Response ~ Cat_1 + Cont_1, data = myData)
```

I get singularity warnings. Why do singularities happen and how I can overcome this issue?
I would appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks,

Comment: Check for multicollinearity in your data (very high correlation among the variables).

Answer (score 3):

If you plot your data the answer is obvious. Try doing

`library(lattice)
xyplot(Response ~ Cont_1 | Cat_1, data = myData)`

and you will see that conditional on Cat_1 you only have a single value of Cont_1 trying to predict Response so R tells you it cannot add it to the model.

Without knowing your scientific question and the purpose fof the model it is hard to offer any helpful advice about what to do next but at least you know what the problem is now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I want to establish a hierarchical regression model where Cat_1 is the first predictor in the hierarchy. I have many other categorical and continuous variables that should be in the regression model together; however, the singularity issues prevent me from establishing such a model. My research is about finding what variables are significant in the hierarchy. I used univariate regression models to see which variables are significant but using univariate models is not meaningful in my case.

Comment: With that data-set I think you are struggling to fit a more complex model. Even with just Cat_1 in the model alone you have 16 predictor variables in a sample size of 80.

Comment: You are right, I am struggling to fit a more complex model. Could there be any other solution for my dataset? Can I use PCA for example with categorical variables with many levels?

Comment: I think you need to pay attention to what @mde

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pay attention to what @mdewey is saying: Based on the data you've shown, cont_1 is not really continuous (it only takes on a few values) and is the same variable as cat_1. So, you can't use both cont_1 and cat_1 in any model and PCA can't solve this - the two variables are the same, just with different labels. Almost the same thing happens with Cat_2 (Cont_1 only varies when Cat_2 is GR)

Even without that problem you have N of 80.  Fitting a model with *just* Cat_1 is already near the limits of what the data can do.

PCA cannot solve this problem. You need more data and you need data that doesn't duplicate itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Peter. In this case, I think the best thing I can do is to fit univariate models and see which variables are significant. Any significance I will get will not be informative, however, because the variables are most of the time duplicate.